# javascript object2object mapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mapping

I'm searching for a javascript mapping library I can easily integrate in my angularjs project.

I use some json objects in my javascript code that are slightly different from the json structure given by my back-end.

I have found this interesting library (https://github.com/wankdanker/node-object-mapper) that lets you specify a mapping through another object, but unfortunately it seems to work only in a nodejs environment and not in the browser.

Does anyone know a similar library working in a browser too?

Comment: On a cursory look, the library does not seem to be using any NodeJS specific features so you should be able to wrap it up for your project and that might be the most reasonable way to go. However, doing the transformation while reading your models may probably be just as much amount of effort.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Last year, I have created a port of the C# AutoMapper implementation to TypeScript / JavaScript exactly for this scenario. I have put the code at GitHub (https://b.ldmn.nl/AutoMapperTS). You can also use the library directly using the automapper-ts NPM or Bower package.

The library is almost fully documented. Furthermore, quite a lot of Jasmine unit tests are already available (code coverage is about 95%). They should provide you with some explanation of what you need.

I hope this library suits your needs. Should you have any questions and/or remarks, please don't hesitate contacting me!

Comment: that's exactly what I was searching at that time.. thanks ;)